# Hibernate 5 - createCriteria deprecated

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-5.x, createcriteria

I need a help to migrate the code with `createCriteria` for `Hibernate 5`, the code is this below:

```
public Curso comDadosIguais(Curso curso) {
    return (Curso) this.session.createCriteria(Curso.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("codigo", curso.getCodigo()))
            .uniqueResult();
}
```

Could you help me?

Comment: To help you get answered, please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a question

Comment: The same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720799/deprecated-createcriteria-method-in-hibernate-5

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of options you can exercise to migrate from the deprecated Hibernate Criteria API, these are just a few that immediately come to mind:

- HQL / JPQL
- Named query
- JPA Criteria API

From a HQL / JPQL perspective, you could rewrite your query as a string:

```
Curso result = session.createQuery( "FROM Curso WHERE codigo = :codigo" )
     .setParameter( "codigo", curso.getCodigo() )
     .uniqueResult();
```

You can also use a `@NamedQuery` which is basically an annotation you apply to an entity or a package where you supply a HQL query much like you see above, specifying a placeholder for your query parameters much in the same way and then supplying those parameters are runtime when you execute the query, like:

```
Curso result = session.createNamedQuery( "Curso.findByCodigo" )
     .setParameter( "codigo", curso.getCodigo() )
     .uniqueResult();
```

And finally, you can also consider the JPA Criteria API.  This is available if you're using a JPA `EntityManager` rather than a Hibernate `Session`.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Curso> query = cb.createQuery( Curso.class );
Root<Curso> root = query.from( Curso.class );

query.select( root )
     .where( cb.eq( root.get( "codigo" ), curso.getCodigo() ) );

Curso result = entityManager.createQuery( query ).getSingleResult();
```