# Subquery example in hibernate 5.2 Criteria API

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I need to fire below query using **hibernate 5.2+**, but there is no such way given in [hibernate official docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html)

```
SELECT * from candidate WHERE candidate.id NOT IN (SELECT candidate_id FROM interview)
```

> N.B. I don't want to use named query or native query stuffs which
>   makes my code more database specific.

In the image below, Black circle is Candidate, White one is Interview.

[image]

Any idea how to run this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720799/deprecated-createcriteria-method-in-hibernate-5/40720954#40720954

Comment: Hey @Jens welcome back.. but can you tell me how to use `Subqueries.propertyNotIn()` with this new JPA interface, coz, nowhere I could find one.

Comment: Read the [javadoc] (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Subqueries.html#propertyNotIn(java.lang.String, org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria))

Comment: `Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Candidate.class).add(Subqueries.propertyNotIn("id", DetachedCriteria
    .forClass(Interview.class).createAlias("candidate", "c").setProjection(Property.forName("c.id"))));
` This is how it was possible before 5.2, but now `CriteriaQuery` of JPA has taken over, so no way to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Interview.class, "interview")
.setProjection(Projections.property("interview.candidate_id"));

DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Candidate.class, "candidate")
.add(Subqueries.propertyNotIn("candidate.id", subquery));

Criteria executableCriteria = criteria.getExecutableCriteria(session);
List list = executableCriteria.list();
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I got it already. When I were in trouble with this, the docs were not updated, but later following Vlad Mihalcea's posts I got my answer. Although I forgot to update it here, I'll accept your answer as solution. Thanks Again :) !!

Comment: You are welcome Manoj! By the way, can you post here link on Vlad Mihalcea's post about this topic? I wounder to see best practice from him

Answer (score 0):

You could use an exists command.

```
from Candidate as candidate
where exists (
    from Interview as interview where interview.candidate = candidate
)
```