# How to add excludeProperty using CriteriaQuery?

Tags: hibernate

I'd like to do the same as they do at ["29.9. Example queries"](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria-examples), i.e. exclude some property when getting the list of entities.
How can I do it using `CriteriaQuery` instead of deprecated `createCriteria`?

I use hibernate version 5.2.12.Final.

Comment: Do you mean you want to make a `Projection`? This works other way around. You dont specify 'skiipped' properties, but rather define 'included' properties into resultset.

Comment: @Antoniossss Yes, something like that, but I have too many properties there so I really do want to exclude only one property instead of enumerating bunch of them. Is it possible without using deprecated `createCriteria`?

Comment: There is a `CriteriaBuilder` for some time now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720799/deprecated-createcriteria-method-in-hibernate-5

Comment: But there is no possibility to add `excludeProperty` using `CriteriaBuilder`, that is a salt of a question.

Comment: And what I already pointed out in my first comment, you have to include not exclude properties into projection.