# session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(MyClass.class) deprecated how to use .addOrder() now

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-order-by, deprecated, createcriteria

I have been developing with:

```
public List<DepartmentType> getAllDepartmentTypes() {
    return session.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(DepartmentType.class)
                .addOrder(Order.asc("department_type_name"))
                .list();
}
```

Where:

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory session;
```

From [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720799/deprecated-createcriteria-method-in-hibernate-5) about alternatives to `createCriteria()`, I have created a method to get lists:

```
public List<DepartmentType> getAllDepartmentTypes() {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<DepartmentType> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(DepartmentType.class);    
    return session.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery(criteriaQuery)
                .getResultList();
}
```

But I still don't know where to use:

```
addOrder(Order.asc("department_type_name"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`CriteriaQuery.orderBy()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/) to provide the order by clause.

```
public List<DepartmentType> getAllDepartmentTypes() {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<DepartmentType> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(DepartmentType.class);    
    Root<DepartmentType> deptType = criteriaQuery.from(DepartmentType.class);
    criteriaQuery.select(deptType).orderBy(builder.asc(deptType.get("department_type_name")));
    return session.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery(criteriaQuery)
                .getResultList();
}
```