# Alternate way for the code using JPA criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria, jpa-criteria

With deprecation of createCriteria() in Criteria class in Hibernate 5.2.2, many of its related functions can't be used anymore. I have found an alternative use for criteria.createAlias(String, String) and adding Restriction from the following link
*[Deprecated createCriteria method in Hibernate 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720799/deprecated-createcriteria-method-in-hibernate-5)*
But I can't find how to substitute in JPA criteria the following functions available in Criteria:

```
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                           .add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("student.id")), "id")
                           .add(Projections.property("student.name"), "name"));
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("student.name"));
    if (limit != null)
        criteria.setMaxResults(limit);
    if (offset != null)
        criteria.setFirstResult(offset);
    criteria.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Student.class));
```

Please provide me an alternative way to write the same code using JPA criteria API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I have found the following alternate way:

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = sessionFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Student> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Student.class);
    //Perform the required join
criteriaQuery.multiselect(student.get("id").alias("id"),student.get("name").alias("name")).distinct(true);
    criteriaQuery.orderBy(builder.asc(student.get("name")));
    TypedQuery typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    if (limit != null)
      typedQuery.setMaxResults(limit);
    if (offset != null)
      typedQuery.setFirstResult(offset);
    List<Student> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

My problem was solved with the above solution. JPA criteria doesn't require `AliasToBeanResultTransformer()`. It transform itself to the required bean.